# What is the <%= tag?

Tags: asp-classic

I'm reviewing an old ASP classic code originally written by another developer. And I keep seeing the `<%=` tags. Can someone tell me what is it called? And what does it do?

PS. Googling `<%=` alone doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it like shorthand for `Response.Write()` (or shorthand for something like `echo` in PHP).  This:

```
<div>
    <% Response.Write(someValue) %>
</div>
```

is essentially equivalent to this:

```
<div>
    <%= someValue %>
</div>
```

The `=` tells the interpreter to just emit that value to the output.

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks. So I can't have more than one statement between `<%=` and `%>`, right?

Comment: @c00000fd: You might be able to, perhaps via some trickery.  It's been a *long* time since I've used classic ASP, and even then it was very little.  I wouldn't recommend doing that though just from a code organization/readability standpoint, regardless of whether or not it can be made to work.  Technically I suppose as long as whatever's in that tag *evaluates* to a printable value then it should be fine.  Multiple *statements* though implies several lines of imperative code, which wouldn't so evaluate.

Comment: The standard use of it is to let you insert a single string or variable somewhere while leaving your client side code intelligible eg `<h2>Welcome, <%=username %></h2>`

Answer (score 2):

This is officially called *inline expression code render block* as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Code render blocks define inline code or inline expressions that execute when the page is rendered. There are two styles of code render blocks: inline code and inline expressions. Use inline code to define self-contained lines or blocks of code. Use inline expressions as a shortcut for calling the Write method.

As for what it does, as the other answer already describes it's a shortcut for calling the Response.Write method.

As for Google, it omits non-letters so it's not possible as far as I know to search for "<%".